# Chrome Unaware of POST Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, post

I know this title sounds odd, but let me describe the behavior I am seeing:

- I am making an AJAX `POST` call via jQuery's `$.ajax` method
- This AJAX call has a max timeout set as well as a couple of custom headers
- Chrome sends an `OPTIONS` request and gets a 200 response (as shown in the Network tab)
- After that, Chrome does NOT show an outgoing `POST` request in the Network tab and the AJAX call subsequently times out.

Here is the odd part:

- Although the request is not listed in the Network tab, watching network traffic via WireShark clearly shows an outgoing request and immediate (successful) response from the server.
- This is limited to Chrome on Mac... all other browsers do not show this issue
- There are a few (very few) instances where Chrome on Mac does NOT display this issue, even though all Chrome versions are identical.

Here is the JS snippet I am using:

```
$.ajax({
    "type":"POST",
    "cache":false,
    "dataType":"json",
    "url":"http://myserver.com/endpoint",
    "crossDomain":true,
    "xhrFields":{
        "withCredentials":true
    },
    "contentType":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "headers":{
        "X-Test-Header.valueA":"123",
        "X-Test-Header.valueB":"456"
    },
    "data":"a=something",
    "timeout":10000
});
```

Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: Is it possible to publish your `http://myserver.com/endpoint` to test against it? Also, if it's possible to share which **Chrome** version/build are you using and which server side language are you using too? Thanks.

Comment: Tried `Log XMLHttpRequests` at `devtools` ?

Comment: Make sure you haven't accidentally applied a filter in the network-tab

Comment: Have you solved the problem already?

Answer (score 0):

Does the destination get the request though?

I'd remove the excess " from the ajax call parameters, since they are not needed in this case ("type": -> type:) to at least odd that one out.

Also what's there at the /endpoint? A php script? Why isn't it /endpoint/script.php?

Comment: Yes, the destination gets the request.  As I mentioned, looking at WireShark, the machine does even get the expected response.  And as to the endpoint URL: This is just a sample.  The real one is valid (and again, the response does come back to the machine, just Chrome is unaware).